# Two IDLEs for Python 3, help me get rid of one

Tags: software-center, python3, idle-python

Without doing an existence check, I used the Software Center to install IDLE to do scripts in Python 3.  Now I have two slightly different IDLEs, the difference between which is not obvious to this novice.  One is called **IDLE 3** and the other is called **IDLE (Using Python-3.4)** I can't even determine which one I installed, although I think it was **IDLE 3**

How can I safely remove one of these IDLEs without breaking Python 3?  I don't care which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the terminal `sudo apt-get remove idle3`

That will remove idle3, which doesn't have that new car smell, so I use

`sudo apt-get install idle-python3.4` so I at least know one thing, and that's the version number of the idle.  I can't tell the difference, nor can I pick a Chardonnay.

Comment: Good.  I've had the same thing happen when either I was problem solving, or the cat stepped on the keyboard.  I didn't really care.  I just couldn't stand the double menu entry for essentially the same thing.